# Detect when User is done editing in TextBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I am trying to great a Windows form that displays a bunch of database data in some `ReadOnly` Textboxes.  There is a singular Textbox on the form the user can type into and it is essentially used as the search parameters.

I would like for the User Entry to be set up in a way where once the user has finished typing in the text box, the data on the rest of the form is updated.

Right now I have tried using the `TextChanged` event to do this, but the issue is that `TextChanged` triggers every time anything happens in the Textbox.  So If I were to type "Hello World", the event would trigger 11 times.

Is there a way to detect when the used has finished editing inside of a text box?  If so how do you do it?

Comment: How would you know they had finished unless they moved out of the box? I.e. the Leave event. Or perhaps by clicking a button?

Comment: You could: 1) use the `Leave` event to be notified when a user exits the `TextBox` 2) Use the Validate event (+- the same thing) 3) Instruct to press `Enter` to confirm the entry 4) use a `Commit` `Button`. Many more (I'ld avoid `TextChanged`).

Comment: That's why there's a Search button beside the textbox.

Comment: The issue is what its the definition of "the user is done", when is the user done? when it stops typing? what if it's an old man that types 1 character every 5 secs? you cant just "guess" the user finished, you need to actually have a way for the user to tell you he is done, the best way is always a simple button that says "search", if you want for some reason a less intuitive way, you can go with the textbox.focuslost so when he click anywhere else it will trigger, also with capuring the character and checking is its the Intro key

Answer (score 2):

I have done this before by using a timer. Place the Timer.start() event in TextChanged. Update your form in the Timer_tick handler. Set the timer to 1500 or so. Experiment to a value of your liking.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    UpdateForm();
}
```